# Laravel 5.4 change base address

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a Laravel `5.4` project and it's sandbox environment is this:

```
http://anything.com/sandbox/abc/www/public
```

I was asked to change it to:

```
http://anything.com/sandbox/xyz/www/public
```

After I change the folder via FTP and try to access the new `URL` I get this error message:

> The requested URL /sandbox/abc/www/public/index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried replacing the base `url` at the `app/config.php` and still didn't work.
The website is hosted in a cPanel server.

Any tips on what I should be trying? I just need to change the folder name. That's all.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That change requires a lot of other stuff to be changed, this is not easily resolved through a simple answer in stackoverflow, I think it's a too broad of a question

Comment: The base folder served for laravel should be the 'public' folder meaning you wouldn't access anything lower than the contents in 'public' from the web.

Also considering you changed folders you may need to `php artisan key:generate` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @DanielGale I'll be trying this. I made some routes with the commands but new I cannot access the root because it's in the new URL hehe

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question: the problem was that there was a redirection in an .htaccess.